# Quantum Key:Logic behind this?

Tags: security, networking, quantum-computing, quantumgrid

I have a project i.e. third party authentication using Quantum Key. But we are facing lot of problems related to hardware so now we are focusing on simulation.

So can anyone guide me what type of simulation we should use?

Comment: What are you trying to simulate?  If it's the quantum distribution, forget it.  No non-quantum system can offer the same guarantees a quantum system can.  In that case, fall back on public-key ciphers.

Comment: Ya most probably we r going for simulation due to the hardware issues but its getting tougher for us.Any help plss...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [BB84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84) to encode your information? If so, look through the stuff that Shor and Preskill [to prove the security of the algorithm](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0003004v2.pdf). If you're interested in simulating this, the [libquantum](http://www.libquantum.de) project has some good libraries put together for defining qubit registers and making measurements on them.